# How do I set install.private in Cloudflare App Hooks?

Tags: cloudflare-apps

I'm trying to store and retrieve private data within my hooks by setting `install.private` as described [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/developer/docs/webhooks#private-data) but subsequent hook requests do not include the `install.private` property.

Using the below App `install.json` and Worker `index.js`, I'm testing this as follows:

1. I click the **Set the Private Value** checkbox
2. Hook sends `"option-change:testSetPrivate"` request to Worker
3. Worker sets `install.private = { value: install.options.privateIn }` in response
4. I click the **Retrieve the Private Value** checkbox
5. Hook send `"option-change:testGetPrivate"` request to Worker
6. Worker attempts to access `install.private.value` but throws the exception `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

### Here's what the resulting UI looks like:

[image: app-creator-ui-screenshot]

### App install.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/install",
  "resources": {
    "head": [],
    "body": []
  },
  "dns": [],
  "preview": {
    "handlers": [
      {
        "options": ["_default"],
        "execute": "INSTALL_SCOPE.setOptions(INSTALL_OPTIONS)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "hooks": [
    {
      "endpoint": "...",
      "events": ["option-change:testSetPrivate"],
      "block": true,
      "failure": {
        "action": "failure",
        "message": "Something went wrong"
      }
    },
    {
      "endpoint": "...",
      "events": ["option-change:testGetPrivate"],
      "block": true,
      "failure": {
        "action": "failure",
        "message": "Something went wrong."
      }
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "properties": {
      "privateIn": {
        "order": 1,
        "title": "The Private Value to Set",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "this is private"
      },
      "testSetPrivate": {
        "order": 2,
        "title": "Set the Private Value",
        "type": "boolean",
        "default": false
      },
      "testGetPrivate": {
        "order": 3,
        "title": "Retrieve the Private Value",
        "type": "boolean",
        "default": false
      },
      "privateOut": {
        "order": 4,
        "title": "The Private Value we Got",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Worker index.js

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest (request) {
  const data = await request.json()
  let install = data.install
  let errors = []

  if (data.event === "option-change:testSetPrivate") {
    // Write privateIn to install.private
    install.private = {
      value: install.options.privateIn
    }
  } else if (data.event === "option-change:testGetPrivate") {
    // Read from install.private and write to install.options.privateOut
    try {
      install.options.privateOut = install.private.value
    } catch (e) {
      errors.push({type: "unknown", message: e.message})
    }
  } else {
    throw `Unhandled event: ${data.event}`
  }

  const responseData = {
    proceed: errors.length === 0,
    errors,
    install,
  }

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(responseData), {
    status: responseData.proceed ? 200 : 400,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  })
}
```